# How to run SQL query on the remote server

Tags: mysql, database, server

I have an SQL script that creates new DB and tables. Now I want to run this script in order to create DB and tables on the remote server (perhaps, using Windows PowerShell). How can I do this?

Note: MySQL and all other tools are already installed on the remote server. I have its IP, username and password. The only thing I want to do is to run my SQL script on this remote server.

Comment: have you tried to use ODBC?

Comment: @low_rents: No, I'm very new in this topic. Could you prove a link to some step-by-step tutorial. I'm searching for a easiest solution (on Windows). Thanks.

Comment: You can use [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) - free Express Edition. Create and setup new connection in Database Explorer, then open new SQL Document, write query and press F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way is using MySQL Workbench (or any other similar tool): https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Here is also step by step tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-workbench/wb-getting-started-tutorial.html